# Use "/" and "%" in Codable - Swift

Tags: json, swift, api, struct, codable

I use an API to parse some data - this works. But now the api uses names like "d/a" and "test%" and I can't create a codable struct with this symbols. Is there a way to use them?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remap your keys. Here is a basic example:

```
struct MyObject: Codable {
    var name: String
    var da: String
    var test: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case da = "d/a"
        case test = "test%"
    }
}
```

You can read more about it in the [documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types)

Keep in mind though that you will have to manually include all the properties that you want to be encoded/decoded and that "*The names of the enumeration cases should match the names you've given to the corresponding properties in your type*"

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! Have a nice day 